# How can I download a file from a s3 bucket url Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the url, and don't want to put in the work to get the file data or blob.  This is what i'm doing now.

```
const url = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/....';

const a: any = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.download = doc.name;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

But when this function is called it just opens the document in a new browser tab.  I want it to actually download the file from the browser.
 Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks,

Comment: When this function is called, I want the browser to download the file to the users computer. Right now it just opens the file into a new browser tab.  Is that clear?

Comment: can you please post the screenshot of what is happening

Comment: and what type of file its is it pdf or what ?

Comment: It is just an image file.

Answer (score 0):

Install aws-sdk package from npm.

```
npm i aws-sdk --save
```

Use this code put your download function inside the success response

```
import { config, SecretsManager, S3 , CognitoIdentityCredentials} from 'aws-sdk';

    const bucket = new S3({
                        accessKeyId: <accessKeyId>,
                        secretAccessKey: <secretAccessKey>,
                        region: <region>
                    });

    const params = {        
                      Bucket: <BucketName>,
                      Key: <fileName>,
                   };

       bucket.getObject(params, (err:any, data:any) =>{
            if (err) {
                 // shows AWS s3 error
             }else{
                 // response of binary data 
                 // use your download function here
             }
        }).on('httpDownloadProgress',(progress) => {     
                 // shows file download progress
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very secure though

Comment: what is the reason behind for insecurity. is the keys are used in front end?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the keys would be used within the angular project? People would be able to see the secret kets in the angular project?

Comment: do you have any idea to overcome this?

Comment: Well i suppose if the files are public and you have a user which only has permission to download files, then perhaps it doesn't matter. I would suggest using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver with something like FileSaver.saveAs("https://httpbin.org/image", "image.jpg");

Comment: what is you get the s3 link and the files are not in public so you should use the s3 keys for the access permission. and not big deal the public files download

Comment: The code is fine, the credentials could be temporary credentials generated by back end.